# getline restarting to read from file when working with fork

Tags: c, fork, getline

I am not sure if fork is the culprit here, but here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    char* a=NULL;
    size_t sz_buf;
    FILE* s = fopen("test.sh", "r");    
    while(getline(&a,&sz_buf,s)!=-1){
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid==0){
            printf("%s\n", a);
            sleep(1);
            exit(0);
        }
        int status;
        wait(&status);
    }

}
```

When I remove the fork and wait related statements, this program reads till end of file and prints each line and exits, but right now what it is doing is, reading till end of file, printing each line and then restarting from the beginning and continue doing this infinitely. What is causing this behavior ? This is my `test.sh`

```
help;pwd;pwd
pwd;help
abc;dbc;pwd
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate.  Seems to work fine.  (other than the extra newlines, but that's unrelated to the question.)

Comment: are you sure? Becuase I tried it on a different machine, the same code and encountered this same error.